# Docker www-data grant write permissions to var/www

Tags: apache, docker, configuration

I'm running a php:7.0-apache Docker image, but I have no permissions to write to `/var/www/html`. How is it possible to grant write rights to this user?

Dockerfile:

```html
FROM php:7.0-apache

# PHP Extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

# Composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php composer-setup.php
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

ADD vhost-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# Open Ports
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Host Conf

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To resolve this you will need to add an extra line in your Dockerfile like:

```
RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
```

Comment: seems to be right but for me it doesn't work : still without success  docker is running trough also grant rights as i can see in terminal

Comment: @mY777   could you please accept the edit and also inside the php / apache contaiener could you run ls -lah /var/www/html?

Comment: it's not working for me neither :(

he is what your cmd give me :

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4.0K Feb  1  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Jun 27  2019 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  357 Feb  1  2020 .editorconfig
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  746 Jan 30 00:02 .env.example
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.8K Feb  1  2020 .gitattributes
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  494 Jan 30 00:07 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.4K Jan 30 00:02 .travis.yml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  18K Jan 30 00:02 LICENSE
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6.3K Jan 30 00:02 README.md
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.4K Jan 30 00:02 composer.json
....

Answer (score 0):

Sergiu's answer is not working, because your volume is bound after `chown`.

What you should do is that you should run `chown` after bound to your volume and before start the Apache.

To do that, I add `chown` command in the `apache2-foreground` script.

```sh
RUN sed -i 's/^exec /chown www-data:www-data \/var\/www\/html/\n\nexec /' /usr/local/bin/apache2-foreground
```

So when you start your container, it will change the permission to www-data.

PS: Your container's user should be in `root` or a user who can execute `chown`.